# Add "My Cart" to top.links magento in local.xml or checkout.xml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Two parts to this question:

1. How can I add My Cart to either local.xml or checkout.xml?  I have a custom template, that never had it called.  Looking for where it is being removed, but not sure I am looking in the right place.

I have tried adding to local.xml

```
<reference name="root">
    <reference name="top.links">

<action method="addCartLink"></action>

</reference>
    </reference>
```

But it breaks magento.  Basically I have a soft add to cart and want to pull the default magento "My Cart" to the header, so the ajax updates on page like it does in the default magento template.

2nd par - Where does the code for "My Cart" live to tweak it?

Comment: As for the 2nd part...What kind of tweaks are you looking to make?

Comment: I have a custom header, which my graphic designer made a custom "my shopping bag".  How can I echo the "My Cart" with PHP in my header.phtml file?

Comment: Maybe this can help.  http://www.exploremagento.com/magento/move-cart-to-header-or-anywhere-in-magento.php

Comment: How about just echoing the cart "Quanity"?

Comment: `<? if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty() > 0) { ?>
<?=__(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty())?> 
<? } else { ?>
0 
<? } ?>`

Comment: another option `<?php $_cartQty = ($this->getSummaryCount())?$this->getSummaryCount():0; ?>` `<?php echo $this->__('<a href="%s"><strong>(%s items)</strong></a>', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

You may have to clear your cache.

Comment: The template for top.links is located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/top.links.phtml`  I can't state enough that this should be moved into your custom template before being editted.

Comment: Cart & Checkout links
Set in base/default/layout/checkout.xml

Comment: Names can be changed in your translate.csv in your templates locale/en_US/